# In Leibniz notation, how do you write the second derivative of y with respect to the square of x?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I know how to write in Leibniz notation for more plain-vanilla expressions like the the second derivative of y with respect to x. But I am not sure how to write, in Leibniz notation, the second derivative of y with respect to expressions more complex than a single variable. In, for example, the second derivative of y with respect to the square of x, would I just use parentheses and write $dy^2/d(x^2)^2$?

Comment: It’s $d^2y$, not $dy^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, if $z=x^2$ and you need
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} = \frac{d^2 y}{d\left(x^2\right)^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much! That's just the answer I needed.